# Salvar value de um select em session

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Bom dia,

Possuo um select onde trago as categorias em meu site php, após a seleção da categoria precisava resgatar o campo value para usa-lo no select da sub-categoria.

Acredito que a melhor forma seria no onchange das categorias. Porém pela internet a fora vi apenas exemplos onde neste mesmo caso era chamado um novo php, no meu caso também esta em outro php, porem neste php esta reunido varias functions e preciso chamar uma em especifico.

Segue os códigos:

```
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Categoria: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <select name="suporte" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Escolha um Categoria</option>
                            <?php carregar_categorias();?>                                                                                          
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Sub-Categoria: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="categoria" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Escolha uma categoria primeiro</option>
                            <?php carregar_subcategorias("1")?>                             
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isto seria usando AJAX com Jquery. Segue um exemplo onde isto é feito. http://www.botecodigital.info/jquery/carregando-um-combobox-com-ajax-com-jquery/

Comment: Muito obrigado, a partir deste link consegui resolver meu problema.

Comment: Pedro, é bom posta a forma de como se faz, mesmo que o link resposta a questão, pois o link pode se desativado com o tempo e sua resposta não vai ter mais sentido :).

Comment: É verdade @MarconcilioSouza. Não me atentei pra isso. Obrigado.